# NSShadowAttributeName not working

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, nsshadow

Can anyone see what is wrong in the following Swift code?

```
func myFunction(color:UIColor) {// Changes the Shadow color on textLabel
    var attributes = textLabel.attributedText?.attributesAtIndex(0, effectiveRange: nil)
    let shadow = attributes![NSShadowAttributeName] as! NSShadow
    shadow.shadowColor = color

    let mutabAttrString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: textLabel.attributedText!)
    mutabAttrString.removeAttribute(NSShadowAttributeName, range: NSMakeRange(0,mutabAttrString.length))
    mutabAttrString.addAttribute(NSShadowAttributeName, value: shadow, range: NSMakeRange(0,mutabAttrString.length))
    textLabel.attributedText = NSAttributedString(attributedString: mutabAttrString)
}
```

I use similar code to change the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` and `NSStrokeColorAttributeName` (it works) but for some reason here it does not work with `NSShadowAttributeName`. I know it is slightly different, but what am I missing?

Comment: You shouldn't have to call the `mutabAttrString.removeAttribute(NSShadowAttributeName, ...` since you replace it afterwards.

Comment: I see, so adding replaces in case there is already something there. If it's a dictionary you are right. Thanks for the tip, good to know.
But that does not explain why the code is not working.